# Build a multidimensional list from an integer

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I need to create a simple multidimensional list in order to trigger an integration in another system. If I have the number 3, I want to output the following:

```
[[1,'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],[2,'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],[3,'https://hooks.com/catch/123']]
```

Same URL for each, I just need to send a list for each number I have. If the number is 7, I need 7 lists in a nested list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This could be done with a for loop based on your input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
hooks = [[i,'https://hooks.com/catch/123'] for i in range(10)]
```

Produces:

```
[[0, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [1, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [2, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [3, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [4, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [5, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [6, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [7, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [8, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [9, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123']]
```

Comment: To add to this, I needed this to start at 1, so this worked perfectly:
hooks = [[i,'https://hooks.com/catch/123'] for i in range(1,10)]

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
def multdimensional_list(i):
    link = 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'
    return [[n,link] for n in range(1, i+1)]
```

`multidimensional_list(3)` returns:

```
[[1, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [2, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'],
 [3, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
url = 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'
number = 3

outlist = list(map(lambda i: [i+1,url], range(number)))
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'], [2, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123'], [3, 'https://hooks.com/catch/123']]
```